# Is it possible to keep *.erl sources and *.beam output in the same directory with intellij-erlang?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

I want to set up my HelloWorld intellij-erlang project with all files in the same directory so I can easily switch between IDEA and emacs/vim.

```
<my-project>/hello.erl
<my-project>/hello.beam
```

Now, if I configure the output directory to be the same as the source, `hello.erl` gets emptied as part of the build and the compilation fails.

I assumed it's something to do with copying resources to the output directory, so I've configured intellij-erlang to exclude `*.erl` from the resources with a `!?*.erl` pattern, but this does not have any effect, `hello.erl` still gets emptied before the compilation takes place.

As an experiment, I've also tried using separate `src` and `out` directories, and intellij-erlang always copies the `*.erl` to `out` irrespective of the resource patterns.

Based on all this, I would conclude that intellij-erlang cannot work with all files in the same directory. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Is your intellij-erlang environment configured to use Rebar ? If so, how is Rebar configured (by default, Rebar uses standard erlang directory conventions). I've never heard of `.erl` files getting emptied on compilation.

Comment: No. This is my first look at Erlang and I was going over the examples from "Programming Erlang".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang programs should be build on standard OTP [directory structure](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#app_dir).  Build tools like [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar) (used by intellij) or [erlang.mk](https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk) build on this conventions.  And so should all IDE's.

Intellij does it, just like you notice.  And so does [Emacs's plugin](https://github.com/tjarvstrand/edts) (that I use and can confirm).  I would guess so does Vim's one.

So if you would like to be able to switch easily between your IDE's you should try to keep to this convetion of keeping you source files in `src` and compiled files in `bin` (and headers in `include`).

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is my first look at Erlang and I was going over the examples from "Programming Erlang" which are just a flat set of files in the base directory. Emacs works fine with the flat structure when compiling with `C-c C-k`, it just puts the `*.beam` next to the `*.erl`.